# Cordova app crashes because of video with subtitles on ios 12.*

Tags: cordova, video, ios12, subtitle, webvtt

Me and a team are creating an app for an iPad Pro 10.5", it's a Cordova wrapped React app. A problem occurs in which the app crashed on a page that has video with VTT subtitles. The subtitles are making the app crash on iOS 12.2 (which came installed on the iPad). First we thought it was the encoding of the video, but after testing different options we figured out removing the subtitle track solved the problem.

We tried to reproduce it on an iPad with iOS 12.3.1 installed, this one also crashed.
Also tried it on an iPad with iOS 10.3.3 and that one did not crash.
Since then we've tried it on several other versions, can't remember them all, but most were in the iOS 10-11 range. They did not crash, causing me to believe the problem lies in using iOS 12.

Since the iPad's are the client's we do not want to upgrade/downgrade them to a different version. Also it needs to be installed manually on 40 different iPad's by people other than us and because downgrading an iPad voids any warranty and isn't that easy we did not want to do that.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm this issue with iOS 12 and Brightcove's Video.js implementation - I sent an Xcode dump of the subtitle rendering failing to crash and Apple immediately responded, which makes me think they know and are keeping it quiet. I just recompiled with Cordova 9.0.0 and the issue still exists - haven't tried on the iOS 13 beta, but it's probably not fixed if they want more info.

Answer (score 0):

We could not figure out why the app was crashing specifically on iOS 12 and needed a solution quickly, since the deadline was coming up, we decided to write our own component displaying the subtitles.

We used the `subtitle` package to parse the vtt files: `npm install subtitle --save`

The `Subtitles.jsx` component:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import * as Subtitle from 'subtitle';

class Subtitles extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.vtt = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.lang) {
      this.loadVTT(this.props.lang);
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (prevProps.lang !== this.props.lang) {
      this.loadVTT(this.props.lang);
    }
  }


  loadVTT(lang) {
    fetch(`path_to_subtitles_directory/${lang}.vtt`)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(response => {
        this.vtt = Subtitle.parse(response);
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { time} = this.props;

    // find subtitle text to be displayed at the video's current time
    const subtitleLine = this.vtt.find(function(element) {
      return time > element.start && time < element.end;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        {subtitleLine && (
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: subtitleLine.text}} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Subtitles.propTypes = {
  time: PropTypes.number,
  lang: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Subtitles;
```

Now we can just render the Subtitles component from our video

```
<Subtitles
  lang={subtitleLanguage}
  time={elapsedVideoTime}
/>
```

The `elapsedVideoTime` property provided would be the elapsed time of the video in milliseconds, this could be retrieved from the video element by using the `timeupdate` event.

This is just a workaround for another problem. If anyone knows how to really solve the problem I'd be happy to hear the solution. For now this works for our use case.